# How to create a public list that can be used by multiple classes?

Tags: c#, list

I have a class that holds the variables for a list.  It is defined as follows:

```
    class OrderList
{
    public static string OrderID { get; set; }
    public static double OrderPrice { get; set; }
    public static string OrderType { get; set; }
    public static double CancelPrice { get; set; }

    public OrderList(string orderid, double orderprice, string ordertype, double cancelprice)
    {
        OrderID = orderid;
        OrderPrice = orderprice;
        OrderType = ordertype;
        CancelPrice = cancelprice;
    }
}
```

I have another class that works with this list by adding objects to it.

```
 class MyCallbacks : RCallbacks
{
                 List<OrderList> CanList = new List<OrderList>
                {
                  new OrderList(OrderNumb,PriceToFill,buysellT,(PriceToFill + LPTAdj)),         
                };
}
```

This works and produces output just fine, but...  I can only access this list (CanList) from this current class.  The problem is I have a third class that needs to use the values from (CanList) to do a few things, and this is just a local list created by the "new List" block above.

So my question is how to do I allow this local list (CanList) to be a public list and be seen / used in classes and methods outside of the one that created it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use singleton! [read here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/singleton-design-pattern-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: I cannot understand what your code is attempting to do and why

Comment: You don't need `static` in OrderList class.

Comment: @maksymiuk I am trying to get this local list to be accessible by other methods and classes.   List<OrderList> CanList = new List<OrderList>  Because it's just a local list, I am currently not able to use it elsewhere.  Make sense?

Comment: So then make the `CanList` property public right? `public List<OrderList> CanList = ...`

Comment: By default class members are private if there's no modifier specified

Comment: @maksymiuk that helped.  Making the list public gets me halfway there.  Now I just need to change the process of adding to the list from below to something that won't require a new local list to be created:  Any ideas on the syntax / approach?                      List<OrderList> CanList = new List<OrderList>
                     {
                       new OrderList(OrderNumb,PriceToFill,buysellT,(PriceToFill + LPTAdj)),
                     };

Comment: *why* are you requiring that?

Comment: I think I figured it out now.  Removing the first part worked.  So in the end this worked:  CanList = new List<OrderList> { new OrderList(OrderNumb,PriceToFill,buysellT,(PriceToFill + LPTAdj)), };

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it, there are 2 ways to use your list:

1. Singleton -
   create a singleton class that always holds the same object and anybody who access it will get the same list. Use `SingletonList.Instance()` wherever you want to use this list.

```
public class SingletonList 
{
    List<OrderList> list;

    private Singleton1() 
    {
        this.list = new List<OrderList>();
    }  

    private static SingletonList instance = null;  
    public static SingletonList Instance {  
        get {  
            if (instance == null) {  
                instance = new SingletonList();  
            }  
            return instance;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

2. Dependency Injection - you can create that list somewhere high in the hierarchy of classes and inject the list object to other classes.

```
// Parent class
var list = new List<OrderList>();
var class1 = new Class1(list);
var class2 = new Class2(list);
```

now in each class you have the same list, since c# pass objects by reference.

I think that you should choose option 2. Works better here